# contact information for Experian fraud

Tags: credit, fraud

Someone managed to get my credit card # and ordered a credit card report from Experian. I've called the credit card company + have a new card with a different number on the way, but I need to talk to someone at Experian and find out what information of mine is at risk -- I don't know if they've obtained my own credit information or my wife's, or someone else's.

The [Experian website](http://www.experian.com/corporate/personal-services-contacts.html) gives their standard phone number 888 397 3742 and I tried calling that, but it's an automated system with apparently no way to talk to a human being. What can I do? I want to talk to a person there -- they're the ones that may have allowed someone else to access my information, and if I have to pay for them to fix something, I will, but I feel like they're the ones at fault.

(p.s. please do *not* list a phone number unless you can cite a reputable source of information -- I am very concerned about identity theft and I do not want to fall prey to phishing schemes.)

Answer (score 2):

Several things I'd suggest you doing:

1. Put a [FREEZE](http://www.experian.com/consumer/security_freeze.html) on your credit (and whatever family members of yours). Make sure it propagates to all the other agencies, also you can put a [security warning](https://www.experian.com/consumer/cac/FCRegistration.do?alertType=INITIAL_ALERT) for free at each of them.
2. Dispute the charge ASAP to have the credit card company contact
   Experian on your behalf.
3. Send them a letter to the address specified [here](http://www.experian.com/corporate/corporate-contacts.html) (certified)
4. Also try the phone numbers from the above link (not the 800/888, the
   714 and the 224 numbers).

Comment: +1. I just tried to order my credit card report from Experian and they ask me for my SS and address on file before proceeding. It seems the OP had more than just his credit card # stolen.